# SharePoint Framework: Client Webpart throwing error when testing through workbench

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to develop my first SPFX client webpart. I followed the steps from https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

1. yo @microsoft/sharepoint
2. gulp trust-dev-cert
3. gulp serve
4. Opened https://my-sharepoint-online-site/_layouts/workbench.aspx
5. Added my custom webpart to the workbench.
6. Getting the following error, after adding the webpart

> Something went wrong
>
> If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
>
> Technical Details
>
> ***ERROR MESSAGE:
>   ***Failed to load component "42b2dab7-a158-4df7-940b-69bac5f3265e" (MyWebPartWebPart).
>   Original error: ***Manifest not found for component id "974a7777-0990-4136-8fa6-95d80114c2e0" and version "1.1.1".
>
> ***CALLSTACK:
>   Error: ***Failed to load component "42b2dab7-a158-4df7-940b-69bac5f3265e" (MyWebPartWebPart).
>   Original error: ***Manifest not found for component id "974a7777-0990-4136-8fa6-95d80114c2e0" and version "1.1.1".
>      at Anonymous function (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-02.007/workbench-assembly_en-us_af4559a08d17da3bbdbb9c0fc7b7ca13.js:145:92225)
>      at R (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-02.007/workbench-assembly_en-us_af4559a08d17da3bbdbb9c0fc7b7ca13.js:140:2381)
>      at A (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-02.007/workbench-assembly_en-us_af4559a08d17da3bbdbb9c0fc7b7ca13.js:140:2469)
>      at Anonymous function (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-02.007/workbench-assembly_en-us_af4559a08d17da3bbdbb9c0fc7b7ca13.js:140:870)
>      at m (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-02.007/workbench-assembly_en-us_af4559a08d17da3bbdbb9c0fc7b7ca13.js:140:570)

I have not changed anything after I created the solution using yo. Still this error comes up with the simple hello world webpart

Comment: reinstalling my packages with 1.0.0  and try

Comment: @TARUN, Sorry. Can you please elaborate? What is meant by "reinstalling my packages" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue tracking this error here - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/632

Update - should be fixed as of last Friday.